# jQuery Animation Toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

This is a pretty straight-forward problem. I basically have a div block on a page that, when clicked, grows in size, and when clicked again returns back to what it was. My problem is that it just doesn't seem to work at all. Plus, I'm sure there is a much cleaner way to toggle between two animation states than an if statement like this, but I'm not sure how exactly to go about doing that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toggle = 0;
    $(".login").click(function(){
        if($toggle == 0){
            $(this).animate({
                height: '200',
            }, 500, function(){
            });
            $toggle = 1;
        }
        else if($toggle == 1){
            $(this).animate({
                height: '100',
            }, 500, function(){
            });
            $toggle = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Corresponding html code is simply

```
<div class="login">Click Me</div>
```

Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: It does not work because you initialize `toggle` with `0` but use `$toggle` throughout the rest of your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you have used `toggle` in one place and `$toggle` in another.

But, this can be done more simply like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".login").toggle(function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '200'});
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '100'});
    });​
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5Wu6m/

When given a list of functions as arguments, the `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` method will alternate between the functions given starting with the first one.  This automatically keeps track of the toggle state for you - you don't have to do that.

jQuery doc is [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).  There are multiple forms of .toggle() depending upon the arguments used so you don't always find the right one when searching the jQuery doc.

Comment: is it possible to animate the height to a 'auto' height, so the height is dependant on the content and not fixed?

Comment: @Amesey - as far as I know, jQuery can't animate to an "auto" height.  It needs to animate from the current height to some other known height.  I think you'd have to figure out how to measure what the auto height would be in order to animate to it.

Comment: OK, but how do you do this with `.on('mouseover',...`?

Comment: @cbmtrx - do what with `.on('mouseover',...)`?  Please ask a new question where you can describe the details of what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you're looking for jQuery's `.hover()`?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that all examples on SO describing toggled animations used the on(click) method. That's 1 action for 1 toggle. But the on(mouseover) (or hover) methods are effectively two actions: mousing over and mousing out. So, as far as I've been able to determine, toggling doesn't work the same way there--I was getting some bizarre behaviors!

Answer (score 1):

Notice the difference between

```
var toggle = 0;
```

and

```
if($toggle == 0){
```

You define a variable named `toggle`, then use it as `$toggle`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".login").click(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle(500);
}
```

Comment: `slideToggle` shows and hides the element, it doesn't just set the height between two values.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see.  One is the scope of your toggle variable.  The other is the common after the single attribute in your animation attribute list.  Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".login").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('expanded')){
            $(this)
                .removeClass('expanded')
                .stop()
                .animate({height: '100px'}, 500)
            ;   
        }
        else{
            $(this)
                .addClass('expanded')
                .stop()
                .animate({height: '200px'}, 500)
            ;                
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var H=H==200?100:200;
$(".login").on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({height: H}, 500, function() {H=H==200?100:200;});
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/q2kp8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I want to defend your toggle solution, it isn't incorrect.

In some case only this way of code will work correct, while `.toggle()` will do some weird things.

Only instead of `if($toggle == 0){...` you need use `if ( toggle === 0 ){`