# Incrementing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a sliding sidebar and was wondering if there was a better way then what I am doing already.

```
  <img id = "MenuIcon" src = "MenuIcon.png" alt = "Menu Icon" onclick = "slideSideBar()" />
```

At the moment I simply check if the `sideSlideCount` is even - if it is the sidebar must not be out, so when the function is called it slides out; if `sideSlideCount` is odd (i.e. % 2 != 0) then the sidebar should slide out of view.

```
var sideSlideCount = 0; // variable used with the side bar
var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
console.log(bodyWidth);

function slideSideBar() {
    if (sideSlideCount % 2 == 0) { // if sideSlideCount is even, i.e. the side bar is hidden
        $("#SideBar").animate({width: bodyWidth / 6}, 600); // slide the bar out to 300 width, 0.6 seconds
        $("#SideLinks").fadeTo(1000, 0.8); // fade the links into view, 1 second, to 100% opacity
    }
    else { // else, if the side bar is in view
        $("#SideBar").fadeIn(300).animate({width: 0}, 600); // slide the bar back out of view (0 width), 0.6 seconds
        $("#SideLinks").fadeTo(200, 0); // fade the links out of view, 0.2 seconds, to 0% opacity
    }
    sideSlideCount++; // increment the variable
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if (sideSlideCount%2 == 0)`, you can swap the blocks and use `if (sideSlideCount%2)`. You could also do `if (sideSlideCount)` and later `sideSlideCount = ++sideSlideCount%2` or even `sideSlideCount = !sideSlideCount`.

Comment: @RobG I think what I'm interested in here is a way to avoid the global variable sideSlideCount; say the sidebar has a News section, when you click that section it should display more options - this would also need a global variable to keep track of whether it was open or not. It seems like I'm going to end up with a large number of global variables, which I would prefer not to. I could just use a boolean, but even that would have to be boolean.

Comment: @connor0728 What defines when it's actually getting slided? What calls `slideSideBar`?

Comment: @plalx I have a typical 3 bar menu icon, when that is clicked the sideBar slides in/out. I've included the code in the original post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply make your code modular to avoid global variables. You should be looking into AMD modules, however to keep it simple you can create yourself a namespace where your code will live.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/BzYuQ/

```
//Define a SlidingSidebar reusable component
!function (ns, $) {

    function SlidingSidebar(el, animateDuration) {
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.animateDuration = animateDuration;
    }

    SlidingSidebar.prototype = {
        constructor: SlidingSidebar,

        toggle: function () {
            this.$el.stop().animate({ width: 'toggle' }, this.animateDuration);
        }
    };

    ns.SlidingSidebar = SlidingSidebar;

}(slideExampleSite = window.slideExampleSite || {}, jQuery);


$(function () {
    //The following behavior could also be in a configurable "SlidebarFeature" module
    //or you could integrate the button directly into the SlidingSidebar.
    //I'm just showing how code can be modularized here.
    var sideBar = new slideExampleSite.SlidingSidebar('#sidebar', 600);

    $('#toggle-btn').click(function () {
        sideBar.toggle();
    });
});
```

Obviously in this case the `SlidingSidebar` component doesn't do much, but as your application grows, modularizing your code to get away from the `$(function () {/*tons of code*/});` anti-pattern will pay off in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what "better" is, but if the intention is just to avoid globals, you can use a closure:

```
var slideSideBar = (function() {
  var sideSlideCount = false; // variable used with the side bar
  var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
  var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
  console.log(bodyWidth);

  // This function has access to all the above variables, but no other
  // function does.
  function slideSideBar() {
    if (sideSlideCount) {
        $("#SideBar").animate({width: bodyWidth / 6}, 600);
        $("#SideLinks").fadeTo(1000, 0.8);

    } else {
        $("#SideBar").fadeIn(300).animate({width: 0}, 600);
        $("#SideLinks").fadeTo(200, 0);
    }
    sideSlideCount = !sideSlideCount;
  }

  // Return a reference to the slideSideBar function so it's available
  // globally, but access to variables is "private"
  return slideSideBar;
}());
```

The only difference is that *slideSideBar* won't exist until the above has been executed, so don't try to call it until afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your definition of "better", but I see your using jQuery which has a nice $toggle feature which can help here.

```
function slidesideBar(){
     $("#SideBar").toggle(function() {
          $(this).animate({width: bodyWidth / 6}, 600); // slide the bar out to 300 width, 0.6 seconds
          $("#SideLinks").fadeTo(1000, 0.8); // fade the links into view, 1 second, to 100% opacity
     }, function() {
          $(this).fadeIn(300).animate({width: 0}, 600); // slide the bar back out of view (0 width), 0.6 seconds
          $("#SideLinks").fadeTo(200, 0); // fade the links out of view, 0.2 seconds, to 0% opacity
     });​
}
```

Credit: [jQuery Animation Toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366601/jquery-animation-toggle). Copy and paste:

> When given a list of functions as arguments, the .toggle(fn1, fn2) method will alternate between the functions given starting with the first one. This automatically keeps track of the toggle state for you - you don't have to do that.
>
> jQuery doc is [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). There are multiple forms of .toggle() depending upon the arguments used so you don't always find the right one when searching the jQuery doc.